# Local constant interpolation in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, numerical-methods

I really hope that anybody of you can help me with the following question:
Consider the set $U\subseteq L^1([0,1])$ of non-negative integrable functions with unit mass, i.e. $u\geq 0$, $\int_0^1 u\,dx = 1$ for all $u\in U$. Further define for any $K\in\mathbb{N}$, $\delta:=\frac{1}{K}$, the decomposition of $[0,1]$ by the intervals $I_k:=(k\delta,(k+1)\delta]$, $k=0,\ldots, K-1$.

Moreover define the local constant and isometric interpolation map
\begin{align*}
P_{\delta}(u):\begin{cases} L^1([0,1]) \rightarrow L^1([0,1]) \\
u \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^{K-1}  u_k \chi_{I_k}, \qquad with\qquad u_k:=\frac{1}{\delta}\int_{I_k} u\, dx 
\end{cases}\end{align*}
where $\chi_A$ standy for the indicator function for any subset $A$ of $[0,1]$.

Now, my question is as follows: Is it possible to proof uniform convergence on $U$ of $P_{\delta}$ towards the identity in $L^1$, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\forall \varepsilon>0\,\exists\bar\delta: \|P_{\delta}(u)-u\|_{L^1([0,1])} <\varepsilon,\,\forall\delta\in(0,\bar\delta),\forall u\in U \quad ???
\end{align*}
I suppose that one needs more restrictions on $U$, maybe $\|u\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq C$ for any $C>0$, but to be honest, i have no idea. My problem is that if you look for a proof of $\|P_{\delta}(u)-u\|_{L^1([0,1])}\rightarrow 0$ for only one $u\in L^1([0,1])$, one always uses the existence of stepfunctions $\varphi_n$, which converges towards $u$ in $L^1$, thus i don't get any inequality like $\|P_{\delta}(u)-u\|_{L^1([0,1])}\leq C_u\delta$ with $u$-dependent constant $C_u$, which would be helpful to find a uniform constant independently of $u$.

If anybody has ideas, i'm happy for any advise. Mabye someone knows a reference where i can find a convergence proof for a single $u$ without just using thightness of the set of stepsfunctions in $L^1$... even this would be very helpful!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniform convergence in $L^1([0,1])$ is a form of convergence of elements in the space, not bounded operators on it.

However, if you're interested in the operator norm, then the $P_\delta$'s don't approach unity, since for all $K\in\mathbb{N}$ one has
$$u_K:=2K\chi_{[0,(2K)^{-1}]}\in L^1([0,1]),\quad \|u_K\|_1=1,$$
and $P_{K^{-1}}(u_K) = K\chi_{[0,K^{-1}]}$, so that
$$\|(I-P_{K^{-1}})(u_K)\|_1= \|u_K-P_{K^{-1}}(u_K)\|_1 = 1,$$
implying $\|I-P_{K^{-1}}\|_{op}\geq 1$.

Edit:
Another example is
$$v_K := 2\sum_{j=0}^{K-1}\chi_{[\frac{2j}{2K},\frac{2j+1}{2K}]},$$
for which $P_{K^{-1}}(v_K)\equiv 1$ and $|v_K-P_{K^{-1}}(v_K)|\equiv 1$.

Comment: First thank you for your answer!
By "uniform", i meant the 2nd statement in my question $\forall\varepsilon\exists\bar\delta \ldots \forall u\in U$... maybe "uniform" isn't the best word, but i hope it's clear what i meant.

Thank you for your counter-example! When i wrote that i think one has to add some more restrictions, especially $\|u\|_{\infty}\leq C$, i had exactly something like this in mind... So what you think, does it work for $U:=\{u\in L^1([0,1]), u\geq 0, \int_0^1 u\, dx = 1,\, \|u\|_{\infty} <C\}$ ??

Comment: In that case $U$ is no longer a vector space, but unfortunately not even then (see edit above).